# KKT necessary conditions - applied to linear sum function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

I'm having issues interpreting the KKT conditions. Consider a very simple problem (from e.g. Economics)

$$ \max_{(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2_+} x_1 + x_2 \quad \text{s.t.} \quad p_1 x_1 + p_2 x_2 = w $$

We have

- $f(x) = x_1 + x_2$ is convex and differentiable.
- $h(x) = p \cdot x - w$ is affine.
- Slater's condition holds ($h(x) = 0$ somewhere on $\mathbb{R}^2_+$!)
- $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Thus, any points which satisfy the KKT conditions

- $h(x) = 0$
- $0 \in \partial f(x) + \lambda \partial h(x) $

Should be optimal. Indeed - I think KKT states these should be necessary and sufficient.

However, solving this and getting first order conditions yields

$$ 1 = \lambda p_1, 1 = \lambda p_2 \implies p_1 = p_2 $$

Clearly, this condition is never satisfied if you want to find the optimum when (for example) $p_1 > p_2$. However, clearly on inspection that optimum is on the boundary,

$$ x = \left( 0, \frac{w}{p_2} \right) $$

So my question is - why is the KKT first-order condition not a necessary condition for optimality in this case? As far as I can tell all the assumptions are satisfied and there is nothing about interior solutions - but maybe I'm missing one?

Edit:

Note that the maximisation takes place on the nonnegative real set. However in most definitions of KKT the only requirement is that the maximisation takes place on a convex subset, which is fine for the nonnegative reals, I think?

Comment: Any conditions on $p$? The issue is that in some cases there is no maximum, e.g. when $p_1=-p_2$.

Comment: Also, are you sure that you are not looking for nonnegative maximizers?

Comment: Apologies, you are right that in this setting there are two additional things - I will edit the question, but we have

$ x_i \geq 0 \forall i $

The price is given, but is assumed that it is nonnegative.

Comment: I don't think this immediately solves things though, since the nonnegative reals is still a convex subset so doesn't need to appear in the constraints (and $f$ is convex and differentiable on that set).

Comment: Ah - no, I based a lot of this on the wikipedia definition. It mentions a convex subset initially but is clear that later on you need to maximise over $\mathbb{R}^n$. Adding the additional nonnegativity constraints gives the answer I'm looking for! Thanks for pointing this out :)